# Table aliasing of the result set

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to store the result set of the given query in a new table.

```
select   d1.year,d1.month,d1.Circle_code,d1.Call_type_code,d1.DescId,d1.CustId,
d1.call_logged,d2.Call_Cancel
from dbo.Table_M_CALL_LOGGED as d1 
join dbo.Table_M_CALL_CANCEL as d2 on

d1.year=d2.year
and d1.month=d2.month
and d1.Circle_Code=d2.Circle_Code
and d1.Call_Type_Code=d2.Call_Type_Code
and d1.DescId=d2.DescId
and d1.CustId=d2.custID
```

Comment: As you seem to be new to SQL, a good habit to get into is name your aliases (d1, d2) with a better description e.g. d1 => loggedCall, d2 => cancelledCall. Since you type it once but read it multiple times, its a good idea to spend a little time being verbose. You'll find it works better in the long run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am creating here new temporary table to just you show how to insert query result directly into table....

```
--Creating new TempTable
CREATE TABLE #tempTable(tempyear nvarchar(20),tempmonth nvarchar(20),Circle_code   nvarchar(20),Call_type_code nvarchar(20),
DescId nvarchar(20),CustId nvarchar(20),call_logged nvarchar(30),Call_Cancel nvarchar(20));

--Inserting the data into tempTable
INSERT INTO #tempTable(tempyear,tempmonth,Circle_code,Call_type_code,DescId,CustId,call_logged,Call_Cancel)
                    select   d1.year,d1.month,d1.Circle_code,d1.Call_type_code,d1.DescId,d1.CustId,
                    d1.call_logged,d2.Call_Cancel
                    from dbo.Table_M_CALL_LOGGED as d1 
                    join dbo.Table_M_CALL_CANCEL as d2 on
                    d1.year=d2.year
                    and d1.month=d2.month
                    and d1.Circle_Code=d2.Circle_Code
                    and d1.Call_Type_Code=d2.Call_Type_Code
                    and d1.DescId=d2.DescId
                    and d1.CustId=d2.custID
```

Below method is used when table is not created earlier and needs to be created when data from one table is to be inserted into newly created table from another table. New table is created with same data types as selected columns.

```
                    SELECT   d1.year,d1.month,d1.Circle_code,d1.Call_type_code,d1.DescId,d1.CustId,
                    d1.call_logged,d2.Call_Cancel
                    INTO new_table   --Here inserting into new table
                    FROM dbo.Table_M_CALL_LOGGED AS d1 
                    join dbo.Table_M_CALL_CANCEL AS d2 ON
                    d1.year=d2.year
                    AND d1.month=d2.month
                    AND d1.Circle_Code=d2.Circle_Code
                    AND d1.Call_Type_Code=d2.Call_Type_Code
                    AND d1.DescId=d2.DescId
                    AND d1.CustId=d2.custID
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do that..?

Comment: One advantage of the first approach is that you can specify data types and constraints that your query needs to satisfy.